Reduce size of QScrollArea to a minimum
Below is a massively stripped down code of an application I have. The application uses different QGroupBoxes for data display. The lowest QGroupBox has a QScrollArea which contains a changing (and sometimes large) number of labels. Thus I need a scrolling area. Code works, but wastes a lot of space above and below the labels. In my case 113 pixel of which about 30 below and 30 above are wasted. I'd like to get rid of them but can't find a way. Using the size policy and the zero margins already helped a bit, but it's still not enough. I experimented with many more size policies and margins at different components, but nothing helps.
I'd appreciate anything, which could reduce the lowest "Data rates" box to the vertical minimum.
makefile:
CPP        = g++
MOC        = /usr/libexec/qt6/moc
QTOPTS     = $(shell pkg-config Qt6Core Qt6Widgets Qt6Gui --cflags --libs)

testerr: qmainwindow.moc
    $(CPP) qmainwindow.cpp $(QTOPTS) -o $@
%.moc: %.h
    $(MOC) $? -o $@
clean:
    -rm *.moc testerr

qmainwindow.h
#include <QtCore/QObject>
#include <QtCore/QTimer>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QBoxLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QDialog>
#include <QtWidgets/QGridLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QGroupBox>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>
#include <QtWidgets/QLayoutItem>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>
#include <QtWidgets/QScrollArea>
#include <QtWidgets/QTextEdit>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>

class qMainWindow : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
  qMainWindow(QWidget *par = 0);
private slots:
  void actionPressed(void);
  void actionPressedHide(void) {DataRates->hide();};
private:
  int             Started;
  QPushButton *   Button;
  QPushButton *   Hide;
  QTextEdit *     List;
  QGroupBox *     DataRates;
  QWidget*        scrollAreaContent;
  QScrollArea*    scrollArea;
  QList<QLabel *> Labels;
};

qmainwindow.cpp
#include "qmainwindow.moc"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  qMainWindow main;
  main.show();
  main.resize(700,550);
  return app.exec();
}

qMainWindow::qMainWindow(QWidget *par) : QWidget(par)
{
  QVBoxLayout *outerlayout = new QVBoxLayout;

  QGroupBox *box = new QGroupBox(tr("Data"));
  outerlayout->addWidget(box);
  List = new QTextEdit();
  QGridLayout *glayout = new QGridLayout();
  Button = new QPushButton(tr("Do"));
  connect(Button, SIGNAL(clicked(void)), this, SLOT(actionPressed(void)));
  glayout->addWidget(Button, 0, 0);
  Hide = new QPushButton(tr("Hide"));
  connect(Hide, SIGNAL(clicked(void)), this, SLOT(actionPressedHide(void)));
  glayout->addWidget(Hide, 0, 1);
  glayout->addWidget(List,1,0,1,2);
  box->setLayout(glayout);
  Started = 0;

  DataRates = new QGroupBox(tr("Data rates"));
  DataRates->hide();
  outerlayout->addWidget(DataRates);

  setLayout(outerlayout);
  List->document()->setPlainText(QString("Start SizeHint %1 Size %2\n")
  .arg(DataRates->sizeHint().height()).arg(DataRates->height()));
}

void qMainWindow::actionPressed(void)
{
  if(!Started)
  {
    QLayout *layoutOut;
    QLayout *layout;
    if(!DataRates->isHidden())
    {
      DataRates->hide();
      layout = DataRates->layout();
      if(layout)
      {
        QLayoutItem *child;
        while ((child = layout->takeAt(0)) != 0) {
          QWidget *w = child->widget();
          if(w)
            w->hide();
          delete child;
        }
        delete layout;
      }
    }
    else if((layout = DataRates->layout()))
      delete layout;
    layoutOut = new QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout::LeftToRight, DataRates);
    scrollAreaContent = new QWidget();
    layout = new QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout::LeftToRight, scrollAreaContent);
    layoutOut->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
    scrollAreaContent->setLayout(layout);
    scrollArea = new QScrollArea;
    scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);
    scrollArea->setWidget(scrollAreaContent);
    scrollArea->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Minimum);

    layoutOut->addWidget(scrollArea);
    DataRates->setLayout(layoutOut);
    DataRates->hide();
    Started = 1;
  }

  QLabel *label = new QLabel("XXXXXXXX", DataRates);
  scrollAreaContent->layout()->addWidget(label);
  Labels.append(label);
  if(DataRates->isHidden())
  {
    DataRates->show();
    for(int p = 0; p < 1; ++p)
      Labels[p]->show();
  }
  QTextCursor tcursor(List->document());
  tcursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::End);
  tcursor.insertText(QString("Line SizeHint %1 Size %2\n")
  .arg(DataRates->sizeHint().height()).arg(DataRates->height()));
}

Adding scrollArea->setMaximumSize(1000000,53);is a crude workaround which works on my system, but that breaks the whole dynamic UI and I'd prefer a proper solution working with all font settings.

I'm not sure I'm understanding your problem. You say that you may have lots of labels and therefore you need a scroll area, but then you say that a lot of space is wasted. Wasted how? Can you provide an image of the problem? Are you asking for a dynamically resizing scroll area that may become smaller if it doesn't have many elements?

The supplied example code is complete and presents the problem. Simply click multiple times on the "Do" button. Area scrolls horizontal, so the additional vertical space is wasted. The labels are simply much bigger than they need to be (taking the available space). The sizeHint()s for all components are ok as far as I did see, so I don't know where that additional space comes from.

Sorry, didn't see that you were adding labels horizontally. All QAbstractScrollArea have a minimum size hint that is also based on the scroll bar size hints. Either subclass QScrollArea and override its minimumSizeHint() providing an appropriate height, or use setMinimumHeight() to a reasonable size (including the horizontal scroll bar's size hint height).

class MyQScrollArea : public QScrollArea { public: virtual QSize minimumSizeHint() const  { return QScrollArea::sizeHint();  }  }; goes in the right direction. It now looks ok as long as the scrollbar is invisible.
